# JSP average calculator

Tags: jsp, variables, average

In my JSP page, I am looping through a series of values and want to work out the average.  I have tried setting a variable at the top to add the numbers to but I do not know how to continually add each number.  In the for loop I simply want to add the numbers to the variable and then move onto the next value to add.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below URL,
  [Code to calculate average in JSP](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/finding-average-in-jsp.shtml)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was a way to pass in the values as they are being passed to the jsp by the controller.  Is there a way to populate the array with values passed to the jsp ? any time i try it gives an error.

Comment: Could you please post your code and what error it gives?